# camel modify soap header

Tags: soap, header, apache-camel

I try to modify the soap header in a camel message. I can modify the soap header if and only if I don't touch the body of the message. If I set a new body to the message, all soap header are removed. Here is the code I use. I also tried to set body and soap header to the out message, with the same result. Uncomment the setDirection part also doesn't have any effect.

```
Message in = exchange.getIn();
if (in.getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST) == null) {
    in.setHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST, new ArrayList<SoapHeader>());
}

List<SoapHeader> headers = CastUtils.cast((List<?>)in.getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST));

Pagination pagination = new Pagination();

SoapHeader newHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://de.company.local", "local"), "newHaeder", new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
SoapHeader pageinationHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://de.company.local", "pagination"), pagination, new JAXBDataBinding(Pagination.class));

//newHeader.setDirection(Direction.DIRECTION_OUT);
headers.clear();
headers.add(newHeader);
headers.add(pageinationHeader);

//exchange.getOut().setHeader("org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list", headers);
exchange.getIn().setBody("<newContent>test</newContent>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a new body to the IN message will not remove headers.

`exchange.getOut().setBody()` will remove previous header and set a new body, `exchange.getIn().setBody()` will preserve header values and set a new body

Use `getIn()` for modifying existing headers.